# Jeditable + keytables clickevent

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I use the Plugins keyTables and jeditable for my table.

I can navigate through the grid and activate jeditable with return.
but if a activate a cell once I can enable jeditable with just one click on the cell.

Something went wrong.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/KeyTable/editing.html

This is the demo, works fine.

My Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jGC4J/

This is the demo code and the code I use:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var keys = new KeyTable( {
    "table": document.getElementById('example')
} );

/* Apply a return key event to each cell in the table */
keys.event.action( null, null, function (nCell) {
    /* Block KeyTable from performing any events while jEditable is in edit mode */
    keys.block = true;

    /* Initialise the Editable instance for this table */
    $(nCell).editable( function (sVal) {
        /* Submit function (local only) - unblock KeyTable */
        keys.block = false;
        return sVal;
    }, { 
        "onblur": 'submit', 
        "onreset": function(){ 
            /* Unblock KeyTable, but only after this 'esc' key event has finished. Otherwise
             * it will 'esc' KeyTable as well
             */
            setTimeout( function () {keys.block = false;}, 0); 
        }
    } );

    /* Dispatch click event to go into edit mode - Saf 4 needs a timeout... */
    setTimeout( function () { $(nCell).click(); }, 0 );
} );
} );
```

The code and the plugins are the same. I should only be able to edit a cell with the return event not just with one click.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple..

adding

```
 $(nCell).editable('destroy');
```

to

```
/* Apply a return key event to each cell in the table */
            keys.event.action( null, null, function (nCell) {
                /* Block KeyTable from performing any events while jEditable is in edit mode */
                keys.block = true;

                /* Initialise the Editable instance for this table */
                $(nCell).editable( function (sVal) {
                    /* Submit function (local only) - unblock KeyTable */
                    keys.block = false;
                    // INSERT HERE //
                    return sVal;
                }, { 
                    "onblur": 'submit', 
                    "onreset": function(){ 
                        /* Unblock KeyTable, but only after this 'esc' key event has finished. Otherwise
                         * it will 'esc' KeyTable as well
                         */
                        setTimeout( function () {keys.block = false;}, 0); 
                    }
                } );

                /* Dispatch click event to go into edit mode - Saf 4 needs a timeout... */
                setTimeout( function () { $(nCell).click(); }, 0 );
            } );
```

will make it work.